# External definitions for ocamllex regular expressions

Tags: ocaml, pretty-print, lexer, ocamlyacc, ocamllex

I have implemented the usual combination of lexer/parser/pretty-printer for reading-in/printing a type in my code. I find there is redundancy among the lexer and the pretty-printer when it comes to plain-string regular expressions, usually employed for symbols, punctuation or separators.

For example I now have

```
rule token = parse
  | "|-" { TURNSTILE }
```

in my `lexer.mll` file, and a function like:

```
let pp fmt (l,r) = 
  Format.fprintf fmt "@[%a |-@ %a@]" Form.pp l Form.pp r
```

for pretty-printing. If I decide to change the string for TURNSTILE, I have to edit two places in the code, which I find less than ideal.

Apparently, the OCaml lexer supports a certain ability to define regular expressions and then refer to them *within the `mll` file*. So `lexer.mll` could be written as

```
let symb_turnstile = "|-"

rule token = parse
  | symb_turnstile { TURNSTILE }
```

But this will not let me externally access `symb_turnstile`, say from my pretty-printing functions. In fact, after running `ocamllex`, there are no occurences of `symb_turnstile` in `lexer.ml`. I cannot even refer to these identifiers in the OCaml epilogue of `lexer.mll`.

Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I went for the following style which I stole from the sources of `ocamllex` itself (so I am guessing it's standard practice). A map from strings to tokens (here an association list) is defined in the preamble of `lexer.mll`

```
let symbols =
  [ 
    ...
    (Symb.turnstile, TURNSTILE); 
    ...
  ]
```

where `Symb` is a module defining `turnstile` as a string. Then, the lexing part of `lexer.mll` is purposely overly general:

```
rule token = parse
  ...
  | punctuation
    {
      try 
        List.assoc (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) symbols
      with Not_found -> lex_error lexbuf  
    }
  ...
```

where `punctuation` is a regular expression matching a sequence of symbols.

The pretty-printer can now be written like this.

```
let pp fmt (l,r) = 
  Format.fprintf fmt "@[%a %s@ %a@]" Form.pp Symb.turnstile l Form.pp r
```

Answer (score 1):

Although the two tokens both look like strings notationally, they're really very different.  I don't think there's a convenient type under which they could be shared for use by ocamllex and Printf.printf.  This is possibly the reason that ocamllex doesn't support such external definitions.  You could get probably the effect you want with a macro facility (textual inclusion).